# skipping iteration in while loop java

Tags: java

I am just beginner at programming and I just started taking java at our school last week. What I am trying to do is skip an iteration using continue statement in while loop in java and unfortunately the output is not what I expected it to be...

This is my code:

```
// Using while Loop
int counter = 1;

while(counter <= 5){
    if(counter == 3){
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
    counter++;
}
```

The output is: 
1
2
and it doesn't print the 4 and 5 but I've noticed that the program is still not terminated.

I've even tried coding it like this:

```
int counter = 1;    

while(counter <= 5){
    System.out.println(counter);
    if(counter == 3){
        continue;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

It just prints 3 nonstop

```
int counter= 1;    

while(counter <= 5){
    counter++;
    if(counter == 3){
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

this one prints 2 4 5 6 instead of 1 2 4 5

I have used for loop to do this and it work well

this is my code:

```
//using for loop
for(int counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++){
     if(counter == 3){
          continue;
     }
     System.out.println(counter);
}
```

this prints the right output...

Now, can anyone please tell me what is my mistake in using while loop in doing this exercise? Thanks...

Comment: If you `continue` there, it doesn't get to `counter++`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(counter == 3){
    continue;
}
System.out.println(counter);
counter++;
```

Here the `continue` statement skips the `ctr++;` statement, so it is always `3` and the `while` loop never terminates

```
int counter = 1;    

while(counter <= 5){
    System.out.println(counter);
    if(counter == 3){
        continue;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Here the print statement will be reached, as it is before the `continue` statment, but the `counter++;` will still be by passed, resulting in an infinite loop of printing 3.

```
int counter= 1;    

while(counter <= 5){
    counter++;
    if(counter == 3){
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Here `counter++` is reached, but it will be incremented before the `println()` so it prints out one plus the values you want

Comment: so what can I do to fix this?

Comment: @robert Why not use the `for` loop that automatically increments `i`?

Comment: I've already done this correctly in for loop.
Actually the real reason I am doing this exercise is am trying to create a program that will determine if a number is a prime or composite. I've done it correctly in for loop, but my teacher said it is right but is is not the simplest method..

Here is my code:

for(int ctr=1; ctr<=n; ctr++){
            if(n%ctr==0){
                r++;
            }
        }

He gave me a hint that the simplest is using continue in while loop so I've used 
if(num%ctr!=0){
     continue;
}
It was obviously wrong..

Comment: Just add counter++ before the continue statement and the code for your while loop will work the same as the for loop.

Comment: @robert This to find how many divisors there are in a given number?

Comment: @GBlodgett its okay now i've already solved this one on while loop.
I've tried this one as a stepping stone in while loop because I just want to check how the continue statement works in while loop, I think I've figured out how to do what my teacher wants..

Answer (score 1):

By the way, in first answer given by @GBlodgett, you know why your program is not showing the result you were expecting.
This is how you can achieve your result.

// Using while Loop

```
int counter = 0;

while(counter < 5){
    counter++;
    if(counter == 3){
        continue;
    }


    System.out.println(counter);

    }
```

Comment: what i am trying to do is skip the number 3 and print 1 2 4 5.
If I use break it will just print 1 2 3

Comment: Check it again please.

Comment: Please, consider editing your answer because your text explanation does not match your code.

Comment: Anytime pal :).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that once counter == 3, it will always hit the if statement as true and never increment counter again. So your while loop will print 1 2 and then execute infinitely.

In order to solve the issue, code it like this:

```
// Using while Loop
int counter = 1;

while(counter <= 5){
    if(counter == 3){
        counter++;
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
    counter++;
}
```

Just add counter++ before your continue statement. Hope this helps.